# How to get a retrofit response which changes according to my request?

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, data-modeling

I want to make a list of coins in my request and send it to server and according to my request my response will changes, for an example :

I want to send a request using retrofit to my server to check the price of bitcoin and cardano vs usd so i will add bitcoin and cardano to my request and the rquest will be like this:

[request](https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin%2Ccardano&vs_currencies=usd)

and response will be a json string like this:

{
"bitcoin": {
"usd": 17155.19
},
"cardano": {
"usd": 0.312429
}
}

my question is how can I make a model in retrofit for such a case which has no key and changes frequently?

for example if I just add dogecoin to my request and compare it with etherium the result will change like this ?

[request](https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin%2Ccardano%2Cdogecoin&vs_currencies=usd%2Ceth)

and respons will be :

{
"bitcoin": {
"usd": 17147.44,
"eth": 13.476023
},
"cardano": {
"usd": 0.312662,
"eth": 0.00024572
},
"dogecoin": {
"usd": 0.096497,
"eth": 0.00007584
}
}

I tried to get the data as a json object but I could not achieve a good result

Comment: Worst-case, use `Map<String, Map<String, Double>>`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.